# 2 datepickers in Laravel 5, but only last value gets saved

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datetimepicker

As the title says, I have 2 [datepickers](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) on the same page. When I fill both of them out, the last value gets saved into the first variable and the last variable is set to 0000:00:00 00:00:00 in the database.

**View**

```
<!-- First picker -->
<input class="form-control datetimepicker" required="required" name="start_date" type="text" id="start_date">
<!-- Second picker -->
<input class="form-control datetimepicker" required="required" name="close_date" type="text" id="close_date">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'nl',
            sideBySide: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'start_date' => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y H:i|after:tomorrow',
        'close_date' => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y H:i|after:start_date',
    ]);

    Election::create($request->all());
}
```

**Model**

```
protected $dates = [
    'start_date',
    'close_date'
];

public function setStartDateAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['start_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $date, 'Europe/Amsterdam')->toDateTimeString();
}

public function setCloseDateAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['start_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $date, 'Europe/Amsterdam')->toDateTimeString();
}
```

Basically, the value I put in at the `close_date` in the view, gets saved in the `start_date` of the database and `close_date` is set to null.

Any idea how to get both values saved in the right place?

Comment: In function setCloseDateAttribute your referencing start_date not close_date .

Comment: I can't believe I have spent 2 hours looking at this.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `setCloseDateAttribute` function:

```
public function setCloseDateAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['close_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $date, 'Europe/Amsterdam')->toDateTimeString();
}
```

Currently it also writes to `$this->attributes['start_date']`

Comment: Can't believe this, haha. I'll tick as an answer in a few minutes!